# Laravel Return value is expected to be 'illuminate\Http\Response', 'string' returned

Tags: php, laravel

Hi have this function which is returning path of a file.

```
public function filecreate()
{
    $myHelper = new MyHelper();
    $path = $myHelper->create();

    return $path;
}
```

phpStorm showing warning of

> Return value is expected to be 'illuminate\Http\Response', 'string' returned

Comment: Your problem is not in the code you have included in your question. Please check the stacktrace to figure out where the actual error is

Answer (score 5):

You must use Response object in return, something like this with helper:

`return response(%path_to_view);`

Comment: I am not returning it to view

Comment: Please show more of the code so we can put it into context

Answer (score 1):

```
$myHelper = new MyHelper();
$path = $myHelper->create();

return response($path);
```

To return View use:

```
return response(view("page"));
```

To return String use:

```
return response("string");
```

To return Array use:

```
return response(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The response() helper may be used to generate other types of response instances. [source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#other-response-types)

To return simple string use:

`return response($path)`